# Javascript not working with php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am using a PHP script that returns 'y' or 'n' depending on the data entered by the user, which is being passed through the variables `uname` and `pass`.
I am using the ajax `$.get()` method to call the php script.

If I try to output the data within the `$.get()` method, it works perfectly but gives a problem when I use an if statement to compare the value with 'y' or 'n'.

My code goes like this-

```
    var status;
    $('#login').click(function(){
    $.get("login.php", { uname: document.getElementById('uname').value, pass: document.getElementById('pass').value } )
    .done(function( data ) {
        status=data;
        alert(status);  //This works
    });

    if(status=='y')
    {
        alert('yes!');    //This is not working
        // window.location.replace("welcome.html");
    }
    else if(status=='n')
    {
        alert('no!');     //This is not working
    }
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: mix of traditional JS and jQuery is not recommended; you can replace `document.getElementById('uname').value` with `$('#uname').val()`

Comment: tried putting the alerts *inside* the `done()` callback?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Move your `if` condition inside ajax due to async nature of ajax:

```
var status;
  $('#login').click(function(){
  $.get("login.php", { uname: document.getElementById('uname').value, pass: document.getElementById('pass').value } )
  .done(function( data ) {
      status=data;

        if(status=='y')
        {
          alert('yes!');
        }
        else if(status=='n')
        {
          alert('no!');
        }      
  });
});
```

Comment: You should replace `This is not working` with `This is now working`. Lying comment bug, the worst bug! :D

Comment: Thanks a lot! Didn't think about that! Is there any way to prevent the page from refreshing after this? Also, it appears that it works  every alternate time. (I'm supposing it is because of refreshing?)

Comment: @Pranav: I see you have page refreshing code, you need to remove code like `window.location.replace` or `window.location.reload`, etc which is causing page refresh.

Comment: Its not that In the other case, I wanted to put some code to change the css of the current page. What is happening now is that it changes and immediately refreshes the page to its original state.

Comment: @Pranav ~ replace `$('#login').click(function(){` with `$('#login').click(function(e){e.preventDefault();` that will stop what I'm assuming is a form from posting at the same time as making the AJAX request. That should solve your page reloading issue.

Answer (score 3):

This is a typical async problem. You make a request, compare the result that didn't come back yet with some strings, then the response to your request comes - way too late for it to matter. You are too fast with your check. Put your status comparisons inside the `done` callback.

Answer (score 1):

since ajax is **asynchronous** by the time your code arrives at the conditional statments the code for the request might **not returned yet**, hence the var status might **not be initialized yet**.
Try put the condicional statments **inside** the *done* function, like this:

```
$('#login').click(function(){
$.get("login.php", { uname: document.getElementById('uname').value, pass:       document.getElementById('pass').value } )
.done(function( data ) {
    if(data =='y')
    {
        alert('yes!');
       // window.location.replace("welcome.html");
    }
    else if(data =='n')
    {
        alert('no!');
    }
});
```

I think that should do the trick ;) ...for further clarifications you can visit the jQuery ajax api documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/